# How do i convert a number to Millions

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum

How do i convert 3.438417e+08 to millions either 3.4M or may be 3,450,000,

Below is my query:

```
SELECT    
    SUm(Pipeline.AOV_value),
    Sum(Credits.AOV_value),
    Sum(Pipeline.AOV_value - Credits.AOV_value) as LeadstobeConverted    
FROM Products
LEFT JOIN Credits on Products.Product_Name = Credits.Product_Name
LEFT JOIN Pipeline on Credits.Account_Name = Pipeline.Account_Name;
```

The result i get is 3.438417e+08    1.457290e+08    1.981180e+08

Comment: Anyway, converting to an integer type [after the sum] will remove the scientific notation bit in the display, like 343841700 - which is **~343M** - which might be suitable. The provided "rules" for rounding here are not well specified.

Comment: i dont know, am a student learning, am doing the above in Jupyter :)

Comment: where do i use the convert bit?? in the query?

Comment: See [CAST expr](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr) in the SQLite docs (which covers it's implementation details and hints at limits): `select cast(sum(Pipeline.AOV_value) as integer) as pipeline_aov_total..` - then the client will get the "hint" to _display_ the value as a precise integer instead of using scientific notation.

Comment: The 'core issue' with the result of `sum` being a REAL (ie. float) is because the AOV_value columns have a REAL type. Perhaps these should be INTEGER (or perhaps not)? If such were the case then the `cast` would add not value as the result would already be an INTEGER. Pay attention to notes in https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html about overflows in that case, which would also plague converting to an INTEGER in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use artithmetics and `round()`:

```
select    
    round(sum(pi.aov_value) / 1000000.0, 2) pipeline_aov_value_millions,
    round(sum(cr.aov_value) / 1000000.0, 2) pipeline_aov_value_millions,
    round(sum(pi.aov_value - cr.aov_value) / 1000000, 2) as leadstobeconverted_millions
from products pr
left join credits cr on pr.product_name = cr.product_name
left join pipeline pi on pi.account_name = pipelincr.account_name;
```

Note that I added table aliases to the query to make it shorter to write and read.